# Office365 Check Mail in Service

Tags: email, outlook, office365

I'm trying to write an app that checks an Inbox for mail items with attachments and the mail is on Office 365.  I tried following the instructions on the Office Developer Center regarding registering an app, but it would seem that it must be either a web application or a native app (assuming to a phone).  Can you not simply connect to Office 365 (using the API) and get mail items using a test console application?

Comment: No sure that I have explored all options just yet.  Found an interesting article here: https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2015/07/13/office-365-api-querying-exchange/

Comment: Nope.  Still requires manual authentication which I cannot have in a service.  Researching other avenues and am attempting to avoid simply connecting via IMAP.

Comment: Do you specifically need to interact with only Office 365 mailboxes?

Comment: Yeah, this an internal project and we have O365 mailboxes.

Comment: You could use Exchange Web Services, but if you need to use the Graph or Outlook REST APIs then it has to be registered as an application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found what I was looking for. In case someone else is in need of connecting to Office 365 Email (or any Exchange for that matter), I recommend the following links:

Sample Code to Connect With Exchange
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/exchange/How-to-export-email-8d89883d

How to Connect/Work With Exchange
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn535506(v=exchg.150).aspx

How to Get/Work With Attachments
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn726695(v=exchg.150).aspx